# Controlling the vignette from the script

Tags: unity, 2d, post-processing

I'm trying to control the intensity of the vignette depending on the distance to the player.
The script itself is located on the prefab. When creating a prefab during the game, the vignette does not appear.

But if the prefab is added to the scene before the game starts, the vignette is visible and its intensity is adjustable. [image: Prefab added before launch]

The prefab is the opponent. Here are the vignette settings:
[image]
[image]

I will also add part of the enemy code where the vignette control should take place:

```
private PostProcessVolume postProcessVolume;
[SerializeField]
private Vignette vignette;

public float vignetteIntensityMultiplier = 1.2f;

private Transform player;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    postProcessVolume = GameObject.Find("PostProcessingVolume")?.GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();

    if (postProcessVolume != null)
    {
        InitializeVignette();
    }
}

void InitializeVignette()
{
    if (postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out vignette))
    {
        vignette.intensity.value = 0f;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to get vignette settings");
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    float distanceToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

    if (distanceToPlayer > followDistance)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (vignette != null)
    {
        float intensity = (followDistanceForVignette - distanceToPlayer) / followDistanceForVignette * vignetteIntensityMultiplier;
        vignette.intensity.value = intensity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which object is "the" prefab? How have you configured this vignette? Please show us enough of your code and scene/inspector setup that a user could reproduce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of your problem starting from a new, empty project, without needing to ask any follow-up questions.

Comment: I have edited the post, please see if this is enough

Comment: From where are you setting/ getting the `vignette` in the Update?

Comment: I have variables like PostProcessVolume and Vignette, if that's what you mean

Comment: How is that variable assigned when the enemy is spawned mid-game as part of a prefab? When we say "complete" we mean we should be able to past your code samples into a new project *without adding anything* and they should compile and work and demonstrate the problem. If you've shared less than that, you're not done yet.

Comment: the value of the vignette variable is set on this line: vignette.intensity.value = 0f; 
And the variable postProcessVolume in this: postProcessVolume = GameObject.Find("PostProcessingVolume")?.GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();

Comment: I'm almost sure that vignette is null in your Update based on what you have posted so far

Comment: no, its not. Here the screenshot: https://imgur.com/rNDLJkR

Comment: I have also added the necessary variables to the main post

Comment: I found the error, thank you all for your answers. The reason was that I was looking incorrectly for the prefab created, which adds (Clone) to the name

Comment: @chiester you can post your findings as an answer, how you arrived to that answer and what steps you took to fix that error. This is also why it is helpful to post all relevant information in the question. The screenshot in your comment is `Vignette (clone)` but nowhere in your code are you looking for a GO by the name of Vignette